# Is there a way to combine dplyr::filter_at results? (filtering many variables at once)

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, data-science

I have the following dataframe:

```
  A B C D
1 1 2 3 T
2 1 5 5 F
3 1 1 1 T
4 5 5 5 T
5 5 5 5 T
```

I'm trying to remove rows that contain all of the same number (e.g., all 5s, all 1s) for variables `A` through `C` (in my actual data, I have many more variables between `A` and `C`). I can filter rows with all 5s  by doing this:

```
library(dplyr)

A <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
B <- c(2, 5, 1, 5, 5)
C <- c(3, 5, 1, 5, 5)
D <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

df %>%
  filter_at(.vars = 1:3, .vars_predicate = all_vars(. == 5))


  A B C D
1 5 5 5 T
2 5 5 5 T
```

Is there a way to chain another `filter_at()` so that I can do the same for rows with all 1s? The ideal output would be this:

```
  A B C D
1 5 5 5 T
2 5 5 5 T
3 1 1 1 T
```

I've tried using logical operators within `all_vars()`, but it doesn't yield the correct result. In the resulting dataframe below, we get rows that contain both 5s and 1s.

```
df %>%
  filter_at(.vars = 1:3, .vars_predicate = all_vars(. == 5 | . == 1))

  A B C D
1 1 5 5 F
2 1 1 1 T
3 5 5 5 T
4 5 5 5 T
```

Again, I'm trying to avoid manually filtering each variable (e.g., `filter(A == 1 & B == 1 ... )` ) because I have many dozens of other columns.

Any alternative approaches or package suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to filter OUT rows that match, or KEEP only ones that match? your stated goal and ideal output are opposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function that can evaluate the values rowwise.  There's a few choices, but one option is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter_at(1:3, ~ .x %in% c(1,5) & do.call(pmin, df[1:3]) == do.call(pmax, df[1:3])) 

  A B C D
1 1 1 1 2
2 5 5 5 2
3 5 5 5 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Old-style R programming using logical indexing in the `i`-position with `[`:

```
df[ apply( df[1:3], 1, function(x){sum(x==5)==3 || sum(x==1)==3}), ]
  A B C D
3 1 1 1 2
4 5 5 5 2
5 5 5 5 2

df[apply( df[1:3], 1, function(x){all(x==5) || all(x==1)}), ]
  A B C D
3 1 1 1 2
4 5 5 5 2
5 5 5 5 2
```